# Python web application with OpenCV in Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, heroku

I am building a web application that uses OpenCV in its back-end. I have built the application on Ubuntu (and I tried it on Windows, too) and it works fine. Currently, I am trying to configure OpenCV to work on Heroku. As OpenCV is not possible to be loaded using pip, I read about using heroku buildpacks which provide customization for the server environment.

The following is my attempt to test two of OpenCV buildpacks:

1. I build simple web server with Flask that tries to import OpenCV:

   ```
   #hello.py
   import os 
   from flask import Flask

   app = Flask(__name__)  
   @app.route("/")
   def hello():
       text = ''
       try:
           import cv2
           text = 'success' 
       except:
           text = 'fail'
           pass
       return text + ' to load openCV'

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
       app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
   ```

   The above code should return either success or fail in loading OpenCV.
2. Then I configured Heroku to use (heroku multi buildpack) by running the following command:

   heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi
3. In the .buildpacks file (that is required by multi buildpack) I put the https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python and https://github.com/slobdell/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy buildpacks.

   The first one is for compiling a python application and for installing other modules (e.g., Flask) through `pip.` The second buildpack is the one that is supposed to load OpenCV.

After all, the whole application did not work!

I got (Application Error) page in Heroku as following screenshot:
[image]

I tried to use other buildpack (https://github.com/diogojc/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy) but I got the same result.

My questions are:
What is wrong in the steps I did?
How should I call (or use) OpenCV within my application in heroku?
Should I use `import` statement or some other commands?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `After all, the whole application did not work ! I tried to use other buildpack ?` Can you show how it's not working? [ask]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have edited the question with screenshot added.

Comment: Didn't you check out your logs?

Comment: @azri.dev Did you end up getting it to work? buildpack-multi seems to be deprecated now. I tried this solution. My application doesn't crash, but fails to load opencv. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I could install by doing as follows:

1. `cd /path/to/your/dir && git init`
2. `heroku create MYAPP` (start from scratch)
3. `heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git --app MYAPP`
4. create `.buildpacks` as follows:

   ```
   https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
   https://github.com/diogojc/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy#cedar14
   ```
5. `git add . && git commit -m 'MESSAGE' && git push heroku master`

Comment: cool, -  works !  (4. is more like **create* .buildpacks file , no ?)

Comment: buildpack-multi seems to be deprecated now. I tried this solution. My application doesn't crash, but fails to load `opencv`. Any idea?

Comment: Any idea? I am getting this error `libjasper.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`?
`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone seeing this today and having the same issue, switch `opencv-python` in your `requirements.txt` to `opencv-python-headless`. This sidesteps the problem with the problematic library file.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should solve the problem of openCV which you are facing -

1. Add the heroku-buildpack-apt to the BuildPack by pasting - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt to add buildpack in dasboard. 
   ScreenShot - 
   [Adding through Dashboard -> Settings -> Add BuildPacks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXatf.png)
2. Then add the Aptfile in your Github base directory which contains -

libsm6 
libxrender1
libfontconfig1
libice6
- one library in each line. See Example [Github Link](https://github.com/Sharon-Samuel-Kerketta/Clothes-Classifier/blob/master/Aptfile)

Now build and deploy and you are ready to go!