# Python Application with OpenCV on Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, heroku

I need to run a python application on Heroku that uses Open Cv as in this question: [Python web application with OpenCV in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270989/python-web-application-with-opencv-in-heroku)

Unfortunately, Heroku does not seem to be able to fetch this build pack. I always get the error:`Fetching set buildpack BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/diogojc/heroku-buildpack-python-opencv-scipy.git#cedar14... failed`

Any idea how I can attempt to fix this issue? It this build pack working for others?

Answer (score -1):

I recently tried this build pack and while heroku was able to fetch it successfully, it did not unpack the opencv zip correctly for installation and I was unable to use it for my flask application.

Take a look at the Anaconda build pack here!

https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack

This build pack allows you to specify a conda-requirements.txt file, which you can use to include opencv.

The steps I followed to deploy an opencv Heroku app were:

1. create a web app and link it to a heroku project
2. heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack
3. add a file called "conda-requirements.txt" to the same directory as your web app and add "opencv" to the file.
4. deploy the app and check to make sure that heroku is giving you something like this in the output:

remote:        # packages in environment at /app/.heroku/miniconda:

remote:        #

remote:        opencv                    3.1.0               np112py27_1

if it doesn't work, check the heroku logs to make sure the problem is with the build pack. If you're only trying to get opencv to work, only use this anaconda build pack, don't add any other build packs. Hope that helps!