# Opencv and dlib, python server on Heroku

Tags: python, opencv, heroku

I built a flask sever app which worked with opencv and dlib libraries.
These are libraries that I used:

```
import os
import cv2
import dlib as dlib
import math
import numpy as np

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
```

This worked well in local, but on heroku, I couldn't go further.

Of course, add buildpacks for numpy, opencv, and cmake on add:BUILDPACK_URLs.
I have worked as follows:
[Python web application with OpenCV in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270989/python-web-application-with-opencv-in-heroku)

At last, I got this error:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.11
remote:  !     Requested runtime (python-2.7.11) is not available for this 
stack (cedar-14).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to iris222.
remote:
```

If some one help me, I will be very happy.
More I hope to receive some guide lines about similar one.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?